# Plotting graph and data with PSTricks: Wrong scaling

Tags: pstricks, plot, pst-plot

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}

% options
\psset{
  xunit = 5,
  yunit = 50
}
% constants.
\def\masse{0.183276667}  % kg
\def\kraft{0.0278661}    % N
\def\bKonst{0.012}       % kg/s
\def\omegaKonst{12.1278} % s^(-1)
% function
\def\amplitude(#1){\kraft/(\omegaKonst*\masse*sqrt(\omegaKonst^2*(#1)^4+(\bKonst^2/\masse^2-2*\omegaKonst^2)*(#1)^2+\omegaKonst^2))}
% data
\readdata{\resonans}{data-resonans.txt}
% plot
\begin{pspicture}(-0.21,-0.011)(1.83,0.191)
  \psaxes[
    dx = 0.2,
    Dx = 0.2,
    dy = 0.02,
    Dy = 0.005,
    comma
  ]{->}(0,0)(1.5,0.09)[$\omega_{\textup{SHB}}/\omega_{\textup{d}}$,0][$A$~(m),90]
  \listplot[
    plotstyle = dots,
    dotstyle = o,
    fillcolor = red
  ]{\resonans}
  \psplot[
    algebraic,
    plotpoints = 1000,
    linecolor = blue
  ]{0}{1.5}{\amplitude(x)}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

How do I get the same output as the following?

[image: Mathematica]

The data can be downloaded from http://gupl.dk/705814/.

Comment: Copy the data generated by Mathematica and paste it into `filecontents*` environment to make us easier to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @StiffJokes I completely forgot to link to the data (thanks for the pointer). See updated question.

Comment: @StiffJokes They come from an experiment and are collected using a computer. (Or is this not what you are asking for?)

Comment: @StiffJokes Found by computing other factors it depends on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
[[0.6005832177,0.00371],[0.6618893637,0.00388],[0.7123448644,0.00246],[0.7324185582,0.00266],[0.7861292525,0.00328],[0.8523181889,0.00451],[0.9109116735,0.00647],[0.9282727060,0.00760],[0.9906639165,0.0114],[1.025928514,0.0152],[1.051970063,0.0222],[1.079096676,0.0131],[1.105138225,0.00865],[1.149625870,0.00549],[1.170242096,0.00455],[1.220155065,0.00336],[1.256504727,0.00267],[1.351990405,0.00184]]
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

% options
\psset{
  xunit = 5,
  yunit = 200
}
% constants.
\def\masse{0.183276667}  % kg
\def\kraft{0.0278661}    % N
\def\bKonst{0.13831}       % kg/s
\def\omegaKonst{12.1278} % s^(-1)
% function
\def\amplitude{\kraft/(\omegaKonst*\masse)/%
  sqrt(\omegaKonst^2*x^4+(\bKonst^2/\masse^2-2*\omegaKonst^2)*x^2+\omegaKonst^2)}
% data
% plot
\begin{pspicture}(-0.21,-0.011)(1.83,0.021)
  \psaxes[
    Dx = 0.4,
    Dy = 0.005,
    comma
  ]{->}(0,0)(1.5,0.02)[$\omega_{\textup{SHB}}/\omega_{\textup{d}}$,0][$A$~(m),90]
\readdata{\resonans}{data.dat}
  \listplot[
    plotstyle = dots,
    dotstyle = o,
    fillcolor = red
  ]{\resonans}
  \psplot[
    algebraic,
    plotpoints = 5000,
    linecolor = blue,
    yMaxValue=0.08
  ]{0}{1.5}{\amplitude}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And here the solution with values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
[[0.6005832177,0.00371],[0.6618893637,0.00388],[0.7123448644,0.00246],[0.7324185582,0.00266],[0.7861292525,0.00328],[0.8523181889,0.00451],[0.9109116735,0.00647],[0.9282727060,0.00760],[0.9906639165,0.0114],[1.025928514,0.0152],[1.051970063,0.0222],[1.079096676,0.0131],[1.105138225,0.00865],[1.149625870,0.00549],[1.170242096,0.00455],[1.220155065,0.00336],[1.256504727,0.00267],[1.351990405,0.00184]]
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

% options
\psset{
  xunit = 5,
  yunit = 200
}
% function
\def\amplitude{0.0125368/sqrt(147.084-293.598*x^2+147.084*x^4)}
% data
% plot
\begin{pspicture}(-0.21,-0.011)(1.83,0.03)
  \psaxes[
    Dx = 0.4,
    Dy = 0.005,
    dy=0.01,
    comma
  ]{->}(0,0)(1.5,0.03)[$\omega_{\textup{SHB}}/\omega_{\textup{d}}$,0][$A$~(m),90]
\readdata{\resonans}{data.dat}
  \listplot[
    plotstyle = dots,
    dotstyle = o,
    fillcolor = red
  ]{\resonans}
  \psplot[
    algebraic,
    plotpoints = 5000,
    linecolor = blue,
  ]{0}{1.5}{\amplitude}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The fitting curve is wrong. (I'll updated my question with an answer at the bottom, in a few minutes.)

Comment: I edited my answer. Your equation was not the same as described in your image. However, you can modify it again. Important is the scaling.

Comment: For your first answer, why did you make `\omegaKonst+\masse` rather than `\omegaKonst*\masse`?